# How to mount AFP share on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, mount, fuse, afp

I'm running into problems when attempting to mount an AFP share on CentOS 7. Currently using `mount_afp` with `fuse` but whenever I try to mount something mount_afp segfaults in glibc.

I'm either looking for an alternative to `mount_afp` or a way to solve the problem with segfaults. I've been unable to find any useful information.

```sh
# mount_afp afp://<ip-adress>/Publications /mnt/test
Segmentation fault

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# afp_client mount -u <username> -p <password> <hostname>:Publications /mnt/test
The afpfs daemon does not appear to be running for uid 0, let me start it for you
Dropped connection
# tail /var/log/messages
Nov 27 15:50:12 hostname kernel: mount_afp[64706]: segfault at f ip 00007fb1a1a68df1 sp 00007ffe2cd61810 error 4 in libc-2.17.so[7fb1a195e000+1b6000]

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# sudo afpcmd
afpcmd: connect afp://<hostname>/Publications
# tail /var/log/messages
Nov 27 15:52:18 hostname kernel: afpcmd[64978]: segfault at f ip 00007fb75dbabdf1 sp 00007ffd3f519e10 error 4 in libc-2.17.so[7fb75daa1000+1b6000]
```

Does anyone have an idea where to go from here?

Comment: You might want to look into using sshfs, which might do the same thing you want to... I don't know though, because I am not very familiar with the afp protocol... [Here](http://fortysomethinggeek.blogspot.com/2012/11/sshfs-on-osx-mount-sshsftp-shares-on-mac.html) is something that might help...

Answer (score 1):

While `afpfs-ng` project (I guess it is what you are using) is almost dead, there was [a recent GitHub pull-request](https://github.com/simonvetter/afpfs-ng/commit/f6e24eb73c9283732c3b5d9cb101a1e2e4fade3e) to `afpfs-ng`, that solves a segfault (though I'm not sure whether it will solve your segfault).

I would suggest several options:

- Try to build `afpfs-ng` from sources.
- Use `sshfs` ([how to article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160630091119/http://blog.austinseraphin.com/2011/08/07/how-to-share-files-between-mac-and-linux-the-easy-way/)) as a better maintained alternative in the FUSE-remote-FS world, though you may also try to use smbfs, but it is alien to both OS X and Linux.
- Use NFS (beware of security risks; I wouldn't advise to setup NFS server on a laptop, for example)
- Depending on your requirements I can also suggest:

  - FileZilla to access OS X via SSH, but using SFTP protocol.
  - Syncthing or BitTorrent Sync to keep your local files in sync.
  - `rsync` to copy files ocasionally, or using cron.
  - Dropbox, Google Drive, ...